# Rust echo server and client using futures blocks itself forever

Tags: server, client, rust, echo

I used [this code](https://github.com/alexcrichton/futures-rs/blob/8e09aea831780fff0928380ab7b5a7a3ca7c1a32/futures-mio/src/bin/echo.rs) for the server, and modified [this tutorial](https://github.com/alexcrichton/futures-rs/blob/8e09aea831780fff0928380ab7b5a7a3ca7c1a32/TUTORIAL.md) for the client code. When a client connects to the server, it blocks itself forever.

**Server:**

```
extern crate futures;
extern crate futures_io;
extern crate futures_mio;

use std::net::SocketAddr;

use futures::Future;
use futures_io::{copy, TaskIo};
use futures::stream::Stream;

fn main() {
    let addr = "127.0.0.1:8080".parse::<SocketAddr>().unwrap();

    let mut l = futures_mio::Loop::new().unwrap();

    let server = l.handle().tcp_listen(&addr);

    let done = server.and_then(move |socket| {
        println!("Listening on: {}", addr);

        socket.incoming().for_each(|(socket, addr)| {
            let io = TaskIo::new(socket);
            let pair = io.map(|io| io.split());
            let amt = pair.and_then(|(reader, writer)| {
                copy(reader, writer)
            });
            amt.map(move |amt| {
                println!("wrote {} bytes to {}", amt, addr)
            }).forget();

            Ok(())
        })
    });
    l.run(done).unwrap();
}
```

**Client:**

```
extern crate futures;
extern crate futures_io;
extern crate futures_mio;

use std::net::SocketAddr;

use futures::Future;
use futures_mio::Loop;

fn main() {
    let mut lp = Loop::new().unwrap();
    let addr = "127.0.0.1:8080".parse::<SocketAddr>().unwrap();

    let socket = lp.handle().tcp_connect(&addr);

    let request = socket.and_then(|socket| {
        futures_io::write_all(socket, b"Hello!")
    });

    let response = request.and_then(|(socket, _)| {
        futures_io::read_to_end(socket, Vec::new())
    });

    let data = lp.run(response).unwrap();
    println!("{}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&data));
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with futures. You have an open socket and you ask to "read it until the end". **What determines the end?** In this case, it's when the socket is closed; so when is that?

Trick question!

- The client's read socket closes when the server's write socket closes.
- The server's write socket closes when the server's read socket closes.
- The server's read socket closes when the the client's write socket closes.

So when does that happen? Because there's no code that does it specifically, it will close when the socket is dropped, so:

- The client's write socket closes when the the client ends.

Thus the deadlock. The issue can be fixed by explicitly closing the write half of the socket:

```
let response = request.and_then(|(socket, _)| {
    socket.shutdown(std::net::Shutdown::Write).expect("Couldn't shut down");
    read_to_end(socket, Vec::new())
});
```

Comment: It is not used in tutorial. Why?

Comment: @simbiont666 because the HTTP server in the client example will close the socket when it has sent the page (and the server isn't using HTTP 1.1 keepalives).

Comment: Thank you so much!